# Swift Issue - Dictionary with Two-dimensional Array in Array list

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, multidimensional-array, swift-playground

I am trying to figure it out what is wrong with my code because XCode doesn't accept to run this code. Any idea what is wrong with it?

```
var dictionary = [String: [[String]]]()
var array = [[AnyObject]]()

dictionary["1"] = [["A", "A"], ["A1", "A2"]]
dictionary["2"] = [["B", "B"], ["B1", "B2"]]
dictionary["3"] = [["C", "C"], ["C1", "C2"]]

for i in 1...3 {
    array.appendContentsOf([dictionary["\(i)"]!])
}

print(array)
```

This is what I am planning to have like this output:

```
[[["A", "A"], ["A1", "A2"]], [["B", "B"], ["B1", "B2"]], [["C", "C"], ["C1", "C2"]]]
```

This what I got an error from Xcode:

> An internal error occurred. Source editor functionality is limited.

Note: The most bizarre part about this if I removed this line: array.appendContentsOf([dictionary["(i)"]!]) and it doesn't have an error but if I added this line then I got an error from Xcode

Comment: What is the error (and where is it happening)?

Comment: @Carter This is the message what I got from XCode: "An internal error occurred. Source editor functionality is limited."

Comment: @EricAya Yes I know about it. The most bizarre part about this if I removed this line: array.appendContentsOf([dictionary["\(i)"]!]) and it doesn't have an error but if I added this line then I got an error from Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were very close! A couple changes:

1. `array` needed to be defined as `[[[String]]]()` instead of `[[AnyObject]]()`. `AnyObject` and `String` are not compatible for appending. Also, another layer of `[]` was added as your goal was an array 3 deep, not 2.
2. Changed `array.appendContentsOf([dictionary["\(i)"]!])` to `array += [dictionary["\(i)"]!]` as this is compatible across all versions of Swift and keeps the appended argument from being unwrapped.

This provides the correct answer (tested in Swift Playground):

```
var dictionary = [String: [[String]]]()
var array = [[[String]]]()

dictionary["1"] = [["A", "A"], ["A1", "A2"]]
dictionary["2"] = [["B", "B"], ["B1", "B2"]]
dictionary["3"] = [["C", "C"], ["C1", "C2"]]

for i in 1...3 {
    array += [dictionary["\(i)"]!]
}

// console: 
// [[["A", "A"], ["A1", "A2"]], [["B", "B"], ["B1", "B2"]], [["C", "C"], ["C1", "C2"]]]
print(array)
```

Comment: Wow, it is working so well. I don't know why I still have issue with appendContentsOf. I didn't even think about this second option what you provided. Thank you so much!